# Getting an integer number by adding fewest number of elements from a list of integers

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, recursion

Given a list of integers `[2, 3]` I want to achieve the best combination of those numbers that add up to `8`. The result should be `[3, 3, 2]`. The below code works correctly.

```kotlin
    fun getBestCombination(targetSum: Int, numbers: Array<Int>)
            : MutableList<Int>? {
        if (targetSum == 0) return mutableListOf()
        if (targetSum < 0) return null
        var bestCombination: MutableList<Int>? = null
        for (number in numbers) {
            val newTarget = targetSum - number
            val result = getBestCombination(newTarget, numbers)
            result?.let {
                it.add(number)
                if (it.size < bestCombination?.size ?: it.size + 1) {
                    bestCombination = it
                }
            }
        }
        return bestCombination
    }
```

This code produces the result `[3, 3, 2]` which is correct.

But the time complexity for the above code is exponential. When I try to cache the results from repeated recursive nodes it doesn,t work. The below code produces `[3, 3, 2, 2, 3]` I can't figure out why.

```kotlin
    fun getBestCombinationOptimized(
            targetSum: Int,
            numbers: Array<Int>,
            memory: HashMap<Int, MutableList<Int>?> = hashMapOf()
    ): MutableList<Int>? {
        // Looking in the stored results
        if (memory.containsKey(targetSum)) return memory[targetSum]

        if (targetSum == 0) return mutableListOf()
        if (targetSum < 0) return null
        var bestCombination: MutableList<Int>? = null
        for (number in numbers) {
            val newTarget = targetSum - number
            val result = getBestCombinationOptimized(newTarget, numbers, memory)
            result?.let {
                it.add(number)
                if (it.size < bestCombination?.size ?: it.size + 1) {
                    bestCombination = it
                }
            }
        }

        // Caching the result
        memory[targetSum] = bestCombination

        return bestCombination
    }
```

Comment: By "best combination", do you mean fewest terms?

Comment: yes. fewest terms.

Comment: This is a text-book dynamic programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem in my code. The problem was in the following part of the code where I wrote `bestCombination = it`. Here I am assigning the same list object reference (`it`) over and over every time a new fewest element combination is coming up. As a result I'm adding elements to the exact same list. What I really needed to do was to copy the elements and then assign it to `bestCombination` and thus prevent looping on the same list object.

```
        result?.let {
                it.add(number)
                if (it.size < bestCombination?.size ?: it.size + 1) {

                    //--------- CULPRIT ----------//
                    bestCombination = it
                    //----------------------------//
                }
            }
```

A correct way would be:

```
        bestCombination = it.toMutableList()
```

I was such an idiot. **Thank you EVERYONE** for spending your time on this silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is known as the *[Subset Sum with Repetitions Problem](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82533986.pdf)*, which is NP-complete. As such, it is highly unlikely you will find a worst-case polynomial time algorithm for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pseudocode working solution for your specific case:

```
n = 8
dist = (INF, INF, 0, 0, ..., 0)    /* size n + 1 */
last = (0, 0, ..., 0)              /* size n + 1 */  

//dynamic programming step: filling array

for i = 4, ..., n :
|   if dist[i - 2] < dist[i - 3] :
|   |   dist[i] = 1 + dist[i - 2]
|   |   last[i] = i - 2
|    
|   else :
|   |   dist[i] = 1 + dist[i - 3]
|   |   last[i] = i - 3
    

//going back through the solution

while n != 2 and n != 3:
|   if n - last[n] == 2 :
|   |   print(2)
|   |   n = n - 2
|    
|   else :
|   |   print(3)
|   |   n = n - 3  

print(n)
```

> **OUTPUT**: 3 3 2

The idea is to fill all the numbers from 2 to n (in your first case, n = 8), storing the "distance" in `dist` and the previous step in `last`, which is used to tell you the path to get to n.

Comment: This question is tagged with Kotlin. Why did you provide a C++ answer? Idioms of one language do not necessarily translate to another.

Comment: Because I don't know kotlin. The algorithm, on the other hand, is generic and can be easily translated for any language that accepts the concept of arrays, there's no mistery and the conversion should be straight-forward and fast.

Comment: Then I would politely suggest to spend time learning kotlin instead of providing a possibly irrelevant answer. Even if Kotlin supports arrays, the features provided by the language are very different and lend themselves to solutions not readily accessible in C++. What works in one language does not mean it works well in another.

Comment: @Daniel you can probably write the algorithm, without it being C++ specific